# Python to Mysql connectivity

Tags: python-3.x

Im trying to take user input from html form and store the data in mysql database using python, as soon as i click on the submit button instead of processing the form the page just shows the source code please help me

Comment: Are you using a framework like Flask or Django to handle the button click (or more technically, to handle the posting of a form)? And is it really showing source code or do you see a stack trace of an exception? If possible, can you show us the code that generates the HTML page and show the contents of the browser after pressing the button? That will helps us to help you.

Comment: No, i don't know about framework like flask and Django , im doing without that isn't that possible?im trying since 3 days i can do nothing , ill upload the pictures .